# how to install bootstrap v3.3.5 Source code?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, npm

before I was using 3.3.4 version of bootstrap. I was using source code package which was working fine.now I want to use 3.3.5 version but its not working I am following this steps:

download the (zip folder- v3.3.5 or npm install bootstrap) and use cmd after that (npm install -g grunt-cli) next step (npm install). but it's shown error image given below:

[image]

Comment: install git, and make sure its in your system path. https://git-scm.com/download/win then re-start your cmd prompt, and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command that it is failing on is "not found git"

You'll need to make sure GIT is installed on your system, and its accessible via the system PATH

You can download GIT here -> https://git-scm.com/download/win

Use this -> http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm to show you how to update your PATH in windows, make sure you add the folder containing git.exe into it.

Try again.